# Error "DNS message ID mismatch" while pulling image

Tags: docker, dns

Yesterday tried `docker run jenkins` and it was ok. Today come to my friends and tried the same from other computer

> Unable to find image 'jenkins:latest' locally
>       Pulling repository docker.io/library/jenkins
>       docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/jenkins/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 192.168.65.3:53: DNS message ID mismatch.
>       See 'docker run --help'.

Have `DNS message ID mismatch`. Tried `docker pull postgres`or other images and have the same error.

UPD: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e

Answer (score 0):

One potential error in libnetwork should have been fixed ([issue 1070](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/1070))

The message itself should indicate ([from here](https://serverfault.com/q/475917/783))

> nslookup or dig received a reply with an ID of zero, rather than the ID it was expecting.
>   As part of the protection against forged DNS replies, each DNS query contains an ID, usually chosen randomly. The DNS server copies the ID into the reply, allowing the client to match replies to queries and to prevent a forged DNS reply from being accepted.
>
> This could be caused by a broken DNS server or broken DNS forwarding or rewriting scheme

One possible solution, seen [in this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/issue-docker-app-after-quit-do-not-unload-com-docker-vmnetd-plist/19495) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/476216/783)

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist
```

Comment: Really, come back home, and at home network everything is ok. I'll try to get error again later, visiting my friends